# Making base64 urls in css work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm attempting to customize the css from VideoJS. You can see the default css here: http://designer.videojs.com/

Note that this css makes use of base64 urls for images like so

```
background: #66a8cc url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAGCAYAAADgzO9IAAAAP0lEQVQIHWWMAQoAIAgDR/QJ/Ub//04+w7ZICBwcOg5FZi5iBB82AGzixEglJrd4TVK5XUJpskSTEvpdFzX9AB2pGziSQcvAAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) -50% 0 repeat;
```

When I copy and paste this CSS into my rails project and fire it up on my local machine everything loads fine except instead of these images I'm seeing squares. I think its because rails doesn't know how to deal with this format by default.

How can I get to understand the line above?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the url there just isn't coded quite as Rails needs it. The typical way to do this is to either use the `asset_data_uri` helper from Rails (if you use an `.erb` preprocessor on your file) or use the `asset-data-url` helper from sprockets.

The `asset-data-url($relative-asset-path)` helper from sprockets: Returns url reference to the Base64-encoded asset at the specified path. For example: `asset-data-url("rails.png")` becomes `url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...)` See here: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

If you can use this approach and point to the real asset you'll probably have better luck with Rails getting the base64 encoded asset right.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I would get the real asset pointers? The css at the link above is already in base64 format.

Comment: Maybe try this... seems promising: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp